# Hide Elements Dynamically in Blade Foreach Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, custom-data-attribute

I have a form in Laravel Blade which contains data that need to be hidden and shown dynamically.
Here is the code.

```
@foreach ($working_orders as $key => $order)
      <div class="col-lg-12 row ">
          <div class="title-md">Work Order # {{$order->id}}</div>
              <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                  <label style="color: #44484d;">Camión</label>
                  <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker truck_type" required name="truck_type" onchange="getOrderFields()">
                      <option value="1" selected>No asignar</option>
                      <option value="2">Asignar empresa de logística</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-lg-6 assigner_div">
              <label style="color: #44484d;">Assigner</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" required name="truck_assigner"> 
                     <option selected="" disabled>❗</option>
                     @foreach ($truck_assigners as $truck_assigner)
                         <option> {{ $truck_assigner->staffs->name }}</option>
                     @endforeach
                    </select>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
@endforeach
```

and jQuery

```
function getOrderFields() 
{
    if ($(".truck_type :selected").val() == '2') 
    {
        $('.assigner_div').show();
    }
    if ($(".truck_type :selected").val() == '1') 
    {
        $('.assigner_div').hide();
    }
}
```

This code hides and shows the fields but issue is I am using classes so All elements in foreach loop has same class and it hides/shows all of the fields.
For example:
I have two keys in array given to foreach loop. So I changes field in key 0 of loop it hides div in both of keys that is 2nd key.
I need to hide/show fields for selected order not all.
What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wbtas3hy/1/)

I'd consider changing the event handler to be set using jQuery rather than using the onchange attribute. Then you can combine [DOM Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods with the `$(this)` selector to do what you're looking for. Rough Example:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.truck_type', function(){
    var val = $(this).val(),
        assigner = $(this).parents('.row').children('.assigner_div');
    assigner.toggle(val === '2');
});
```

In this example we used the [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), and [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) methods. There are many different methods that could be used though. For instance the [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) method:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.truck_type', function(){
    var val = $(this).val(),
        assigner = $(this).parents('.title-md').next();
    assigner.toggle(val === '2');
});
```

There are also the [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/), and [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) methods:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select.truck_type', function(){
    var val = $(this).val(),
        assigner = $(this).closest('.row').find('.assigner_div');
    assigner.toggle(val === '2');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$key` in `foreach` loop to accomplish the given task. Pass the `$key` to the `getOrderFields` function and change the class name according to the `$key` as well. Following is the changed code segments according to your problem.

```
...
  <select class="form-control kt-selectpicker truck_type" required name="truck_type" onchange="getOrderFields({{ $key }})">
...
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 assigner_div_{{ $key }}">
...
```

In script,

```
function getOrderFields(key) {
   if ($(".truck_type :selected").val() == '2') {
      $('.assigner_div_' + key).show();
   }
   if ($(".truck_type :selected").val() == '1') {
      $('.assigner_div_' + key).hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...This is exactly what I did and it is working great.. Thanks